# Termux can't run shell script

Tags: shell, termux

As stated in the topic above, I am trying to configure a hardware using shell script which is downloaded from the official website of Orange Pi. Am using termux as the medium to run the shell script of the config file. But, whenever I try running the shell script, it shows permission denied. The shell script needs a rooted hardware. I have rooted the Orange Pi. I am running the shell script in 'su' state. Still it shows permission is denied. Any suggestion?

I have run: './script.sh' and 'sudo ./script.sh'
Both of the command above is run in 'su' state

both of it shows permission is denied. Any suggestion on how should I do it?

Comment: What are the permissions on the script?

Comment: the script only states that the script requires root privilege.

Comment: A script can not **state** anything. We need to know which permission bits you have given to your script (i.e. do a `ls script.sh` or `stat script.sh` to find out).

Comment: This isn't really an `if/then/else` programming problem as appropriate for StackOverflow (IMHO). Please delete here and repost to [raspberrypi.se] or [su]. In any case you'll what to include the output of `/bin/ls -l ./script.sh` in the body of your question (NOT IN COMMENTS!). Good luck.

Comment: by running the command of 'stat script.sh', the script.sh output:
Access: (660/rw-rw---) Uid: (0/root) Gid: (1015/sdcard_rw)

Comment: The error shows invalid gid/uid for the 'su'. changing the uid/gid of the su is not recommended. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

In android phones I deal with shell scripts in custom recovery's terminal (TWRP or Orange Fox) or through CMD in windows while the phone is still in recovery mode (I am to use it without root in recovery ). I don't know if it works the same way for Orange Pi OS (its based on android), also try using termux from github for F-Droid, Play store version is not working properly and is very old.

Comment: Currently, am using termux downloaded from the F-Droid. For the recovery mode, I don't try it yet. Am not sure too whether Orange Pi and android phones are the same. But, thank you for the opinion given.